# How long does a headphone last on a given battery?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, voltage, batteries

[Sennheiser HD 598](https://en-in.sennheiser.com/high-end-headphones-audio-stereo-hifi-hd-598) has 50Ω impedance. It has a 3.6mm cable, but I am planning to do a simple DIY project to replace the cable with a bluetooth receiver, a 3.7V 1000mAh battery (and a charging board).

My calculation for how long it will last, according to Ohms law,
$$
3.7V = I\times50Ω \implies I = 74mA
$$
which should last me $\frac{1000mAh}{74mA} = 13.5 hours$. Is this correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Dont forget to figure out the power draw for the Bluetooth signal, that must be factored in too.

Comment: The 3.7V is not placed across the headphone impedance, is it? Your calculation makes no sense to me.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The battery is connected to the bluetooth receiver which is connected to the headphones.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri I'm trying to make my wired headphone wireless. I'm connecting the Left/right speaker wires to the left/right pin in the Bluetooth receiver. The bluetooth receiver needs power, so, I'm connecting the battery.

I still don't understand how the headphone itself is powered. I assumed that the receiver supplies the current as well, and tried to do my calculation. If it doesn't make sense, can you please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Just for completeness, this is the bluetooth receiver I'm planning to use: https://www.amazon.in/Electronic-Spices-Bluetooth-Receiver-Transmitter/dp/B07V3WS9XN

Comment: Please let me know if this is not a right question for this sub, can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: I feel like you'll get a more comprehensive answer on electrical engineering stackexchange as you can plan out and look at circuits there much better than here.

Comment: Why people are dealing with this in comments when it's clearly for [electronics.se] I do not know.

Answer (score 0):

First, questions about this type of project should be asked at the Electrical Engineering site.

However, there is a conceptual issue here that, on my view, needs to be addressed independent of the context.

Specifically, you're misapplying Ohm's law. Ohm's law defines the ideal resistor circuit element by relating the voltage across the resistor to the current through.

The headphone speakers do not have the 3.7 VDC battery voltage across so the calculation you have in your question doesn't make any sense.

Between the battery and the headphone speaker's 50 ohm impedance is an audio amplifier of some type that *modulates* the voltage across the headphone speakers (ideally) in proportion to the audio input signal (regardless of how, e.g., Bluetooth, the audio signal arrives at the amplifier input).

Thus, the calculation of the battery life will ultimately require some assumption about the audio signal.